# hapijs yar doesn't work

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am having this in one handler (`api/user/login`):

```
 request.yar.set('userSession', {userId: doc.userId});
 console.log(request.yar.get('userSession'));
```

in second handler I have this (`api/user/isLoggedIn`):

```
 console.log(request.yar.get('userSession'));
```

when I go in browser and do this in console:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:3004/api/user/login',
method: 'POST',
data: {
    email: 'durisvk2@gmail.com',
    password: 'jjuurr123'
},
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
})
```

the server outputs: `{userId: 'ASDFGHJKLZX'}`

BUT when I do this in Chrome Console:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:3004/api/user/isLoggedIn',
method: 'GET',
data: {
},
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
})
```

I get in console `undefined`

why isn't it storing session from one request to another?

Comment: Interesting, when I do `isSecure: false` it works...